# Web Publish no longer opening site after completion VS 2022

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2022

I started having this issue recently when publishing my web app. Previously it would open the site after a successful publish, but it is no longer doing that. I have my destination url set in the publish settings.

There is also a notification that an error occurred in the publish profile window, even though the publish succeeded with no errors (some warnings but no errors):

[image]
[image]

I validate the deployment is successful once the site opens up in the browser, which is easier than hunting through the output window to check the logs. There are also no timestamps in the logs to indicate when the last deployment was, so often I deploy multiple times because I forgot when I did it last. I am on VS 2022 Community Build 17.3.6.

Comment: are you able to add the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [image][image]

In your Image, Publishing to Azure is Succeeded but the Visual Studio IDE showing publish is failed.

The same issue has been registered few days back in the [MS Q&A Forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1029534/publish-to-azure-succeeds-but-visual-studio-says-t.html).

In the above issue, there are few troubleshooting steps suggested from the Product Team SME's @[LanHuang-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/8406356/lanhuang-msft.html) and @[ajkuma-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/16348/ajkuma-msft.html) were:

- Open VS IDE as Administrator, Update it to the latest Version.
- Delete the .vs folder from your project folder and pubxml file if it is available.
- Clean, Rebuild and Publish.

Recently, I have checked by publishing the .NET 6 Core Web App to Azure Web App using `VS 2022 IDE latest Version 17.3.6` and it is working as expected in publishing to Azure:

[image]

Comment: The solution that worked for me was deleting and reconfiguring my publish profiles!